# How to rewrite code for vector creation in common case?

Tags: r, vector

I need to create the vector `cx=(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)`. I have wrote a code.

```
k <- 3
tmp <- matrix(0, k, k)
tmp[1,] <-rep(c(1), times = k)
tmp[2,] <-rep(c(2), times = k)
tmp[3,] <-rep(c(3), times = k)

cx <-c(t(tmp))
cx
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Result is right for me but the code is very long.
How to rewrite code for arbitrary number `k`?
My variant is:

```
k <- 3
tmp <- matrix(0, k, k)
for(i in 1:k) tmp[i,] <-rep(c(i), times = k)
cx <-c(t(tmp))
```

Comment: Use the `each` argument of `rep`: `rep(1:3, each = 3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rep` function is good enough, but the Kronecker product is worth mentioning.

```
kronecker(1:3, rep(1, 3))
```

Comment: Right :p  Just to socialize kronecker function...